# Determine Regex expression for a specific format of a string

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression for a string with the format XWS (34) 12345678
It should start with XW, followed by any letter, then a space and then two numbers within the parentheses, followed by another space and then followed by 8 letters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: the last 8 digits can be alphanumeric or only numbers, as you have stated letters but the example shows numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the last 8 characters can be alphanumeric, here is the answer:

```
^XW[A-Z]+[ ]{1}\([0-9]{2}\)[ ]{1}[A-Z0-9]{8}$
```

Considering that the last 8 characters are numeric-only:

```
^XW[A-Z]+[ ]{1}\([0-9]{2}\)[ ]{1}[0-9]{8}$
```